# Regex to get string between html tags: stop selection at the first match of closing tag

Tags: regex

I want to get html between a ul tag. It resembles the following:

```html
<nav id="navi_list_box" class="local_nav favorite">
  <ul id="navi_list">
    <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/mypage">Foo</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/mypage/favorite">Bar</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/mypage/change">Baz</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Just to make sure this won't be selected</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to get html of `ul#navi_list`.

This is what I have done so far:

```regex
<ul[^>]*id(\s)*=('|")navi_list(\s)*('|")>(\n|\r|(\n\r)|.)*(</ul>)
```

It selects html of `#navi_list` but also html of the second `ul` tag.

How can I stop selection before the second `ul` tag?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454   sorry I couldnt resist

Comment: @PA I enjoyed the original answer. But stupidly there is some PHP framework that you should to hook before view rendering and change its html content. Yes with regex. It is meant to work with regex. It's mostly used shopping mall framework in Japan. Anyway, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```regex
<ul[^>]*id(\s)*=('|")navi_list(\s)*('|")>((.|\n|\r|(\n\r))*?)</ul>
```

The following regex will select all html between a tag and its closing counterpart.

```regex
<TAG\b[^>]*>((.|\n|\r|(\n\r))*?)</TAG>
```